# How do I emulate a MIDDLE MOUSE CLICK in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

So, I am inside of a google classroom with 8 classes and I want to make it so selenium middle clicks and opens those classes in a new tab.

For example, this is one of my class and I have it finding element by xpath and I want to make it so selenium opens this element in a new tab by middle mouse click. How would I go about doing that?

modern_history = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/ol/li[1]/div[1]/div[3]/h2/a[1]/div[1]')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open the new window with javascript:

```py
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/ol/li[1]/div[1]/div[3]/h2/a[1]")

driver.execute_script("window.open('arguments[0]');", element.get_attribute("href")
```

In addition you should try finding your elements without that long xPath, as it is very fragile.

Comment: Hey, your code worked! thank you!
could you tell me how the second line works?